# DataGridTemplateColumn InvokeCommandAction Template

Tags: wpf, datagridtemplatecolumn, celltemplate

I'm using a UserControl where the main control inside is a datagrid.
All is working. 
However, some lines of my code are redundant since I implement the same trigger in each of the 48 columns.

How do I make a template for the datagridtemplatecolumn of the following code snippet?
The only thing different in each column is the bound property. All the triggers and formatting are the same.

I would appreciate your help!

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="5" MaxWidth="10">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Background="{Binding _5, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=hourSlotColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="-1">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.StartCellCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                            Path=DataContext.LastCellCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.MouseDragCom}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" MaxWidth="10">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Background="{Binding _5_5, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=hourSlotColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="-1">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.StartCellCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                            Path=DataContext.LastCellCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.MouseDragCom}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="6" MaxWidth="10">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Background="{Binding _6, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=hourSlotColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="-1">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.StartCellCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                            Path=DataContext.LastCellCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.MouseDragCom}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Column"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**EDIT**

So I followed Sheridan's suggestion with some revisions to make it shorter and simpler. Although our project leader suggested this method before, I had no idea on how to implement it prior to Sheridan's input. Kudos to him

This is the code for the UserControl we used. What it contains is exactly the same triggers we used from our original code above:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Widget5.View.DGInfo"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Widget5.Converter"  
             xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Widget5.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="20">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converter:DataGridInfoToParamConverter x:Key="dgInfoConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TextBlock  Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DGInfo}}}" Margin="-1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                Path=DataContext.StartCellCommand}" >
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Column" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                        Path=DataContext.LastCellCommand}" >
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Column" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                Path=DataContext.MouseDragCom}" >
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Column" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

And on the DataGridTemplateColumn itself, we just added the UserControl(DGInfo) and set its background like we did before. Saved thousands of lines because of this.

```
<DataGrid ...>
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="6" MaxWidth="10">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <View:DGInfo Background="{Binding _6, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=hourSlotColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: @Sheridan - Hi sir, can you help me with this?  I tagged you as you proved to be one of the the biggest help on my last inquiry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `DataTemplate`s are exactly the same then just put one into a `Resources` section and then simply reference it:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TheDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock
            Background="{Binding _5_5, Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=hourSlotColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Margin="-1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                Path=DataContext.StartCellCommand}">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Column"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                        Path=DataContext.LastCellCommand}">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Column"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                Path=DataContext.MouseDragCom}">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Column"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource TheDataTemplate}" 
Header="" MaxWidth="10" />
...
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so if you have different `Binding`s inside the `DataTemplate`, then you'll have to use a `UserControl` instead. You will then be able to declare `DependencyProperty`s for the variable properties and bind to them from the `DataGridColumn`:

```
<UserControl ... >
    <TextBlock
        Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type yourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}"
        Margin="-1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding StartCellCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type yourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dgInfoConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Column"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type yourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}" />
                            <Binding Path="SomeProperty"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type yourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            ...
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

If you define a `DependencyProperty` for each different `Binding`, then you'll be able to set them like this:

```
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" MaxWidth="10">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <yourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl Background="{Binding _5_5, 
Converter={StaticResource  ResourceKey=hourSlotColorConverter}, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" StartCellCommand="{Binding RelativeSource=
{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.StartCellCommand}" 
Column="{Binding Column, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
DataGridCell}}}" SomeProperty="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn >
...
```

It's still a lot of code, but it's much less than before. I didn't finish this example for all of your properties, but I'm guessing that you'll get the idea.

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply sir. I agree you are correct if they would all be the same. However, each cell is bound to a different property. Only the triggers on each cell are the same.

Comment: Thanks! To minimize the code though, we opted to just use my previous Trigger s on the TextBlock s on the UserControl you suggested. Adding the UserControl to the DataTemplate was then very simple. Just set the UserControl 's background and converter as before. I will edit my question to show my revision to your suggestion in case anyone else encounter a similar problem.